# What is the meaning of a cpu bottlenecking a graphics card?

Tags: cpu, gpu

I have a core i5 2400 processor and i intend to order for a Zotac GT 710 video card. So i decided to check for the bottle neck percentage from PC Builds. And they suggested that that that graphic card is too weak for that processor at 1080p. So my question is what does the `1080p` represent and what is the real meaning `graphic card too weak for your processor`, because i thought a processor could be weak for the graphics card and not the reverse, Thanks. And also why aren't PCBuilds giving suggestions for bottle necks at `720p` and below. Will I be okay if I ignore that warning and order for it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do anything your graphics card needs instructions. It needs geometry data. It needs positions of objects. It needs textures.

In order to calculate positions of your character model your CPU takes in information from your keyboard and mouse. It has information that shows how the character model changes over time, the model animations. Calculation of position, orientation, animation and so on all require the CPU to do work before passing onto the GPU to draw it.

The instructions might be "simple" from the graphics card point of view: "here is a model, apply these textures" or it could be more complex "take this model, apply transforms to this area or limb to make it look like this".

Having lots of elements in a scene that change position to each other or need on-the-fly transformation can quickly shift the balance from GPU (drawing) bottlenecks to CPU (calculation) bottlenecks. The CPU might be calculating the wider world and movement of objects that are not on-screen yet, *but could be at any moment*.

It is the type and quantity of calculations in a game or program that determine whether you are CPU or GPU bottlenecked.

If your GPU is constantly waiting for the CPU to give it data on the scene or models then it will not be able to perform at its best. Your GPU is bottlenecked by the CPU.

If your CPU can give your GPU everything it needs before it needs it then your GPU becomes the bottleneck. If your CPU can put out all the information needed to calculate the "world" at 60fps but your graphics card cannot draw it that fast then your GPU is the bottleneck.

If your GPU can put out 60 fps (or your screen refresh rate) without waiting then you are not bottlenecked (except by your display frequency).

All that said, the 710 is a pretty weak card by today's standards. Games have a lot of visual processing going on and I doubt a 710 could process graphics on a modern game to put out a high framerate.

Comment: How is the monitor refresh rate affecting this?I thought only gpu, cpu mattered

Comment: The monitor refresh rate can set an upper bound on how fast your system expects to send completed frames out (if vertical sync is enabled, which it should be if you care about quality of image). Having a graphics card that *can* put out 100fps but with vsync on a 60hz display means you are limited to 60fps. You can turn off vsync but then you end up with "tearing" where the image being drawn on the screen changes mid-frame.

Comment: The last two lines are pure technical didn't understand a thing. So you mean to say the Refresh rate has the same meaning has gameplay FPS?

Comment: My monitor supports a maximum of 80, does that mean i can play with FPS higher than 60?

Comment: If your CPU and GPU can put out graphics fast enough then yes, you can play in theory at 80fps. Hz and fps are opposite sides of looking at things. Your computer might be able to generate 80 frames in a second, but your display can only regenerate its image at 80 cycles (Hz) per second. They are related but not technically the same.

Comment: Fps is your computer saying "I generated this many images this second". Monitor refresh rate Hz is your monitor saying "I can display up to this many images in a second"

Comment: Hz is the rate at which the screen will refresh the pixels, while FPS is the number of frames per second generated by your system, you can have 120 FPS on a 90 Hz monitor.  However, the clarify of the image will be better, on a monitor that supports 120 Hz or 144 Hz (which are typical refresh rates for display panels). 1080p and 720p are resolution standards.

Comment: @Ramhound with the introduction of VRR monitors which can match to the refresh rate of the incoming signal I considered that the problem was somewhat reversed. The computer can now generate "up to" a particular frame rate while the monitor can sync "down to" whatever the computer can output. Your point is still very much valid though, the refresh rate of the screen is technically the peak screen refresh rate that the monitor supports.

Comment: @Mokubai - I was only attempting to illustrate that the Refresh Rate is a feature of the display panel itself while FPS is dependent on the hardware within the computer.  Everything goes out the window once you talk about FPS with regards to video itself. Say for instance the FPS on a 4K Blu-ray disk that’s entirely up to the codecs and often times hardware specific of the display (say on a fancy 5k Apple display). My comment wasn’t 100% technical explanation (no comment could be) and I am by far the last person to talk about video and display technology. I only get by with my knowledge

Comment: @Ramhound I wasn't having a go. From a technical refresh rate perspective you are 100% correct, I just wanted to mention that there are considerations that make modern displays somewhat "odd" in that Variable Refresh Rate monitors can work down at most framerates that a computer would be able to output. I suspect that the hardware of the panel itself works at the native 144Hz, but that the buffers behind the LCD panel work at whatever they are given and that a human being can't actually see the difference between the two.

Comment: I personally cannot tell the difference between 120 Hz and 144 Hz so I would have to agree :-)